# Compute matrix $BA$ if $AB$ is given

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $A, B$ respectively be a matrix with size $4\times 2$ and $2\times4$. If
>   $AB = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&-1&0\\0&1&0&-1\\-1&0&1&0\\0&-1&0&1\end{pmatrix} \\$
>   then $BA$ is equal to what?

For this one, I really don't have much idea to think. Maybe eigen things work here because sometime it shows miracles. Could you help me? I have discussed this one week ago with my friend in college, but didn't find the way

Comment: Ops sorry I didn’t read the limitation on sides!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns of $A$ must be able to combine to create the row space of $AB$, and this row space is easy to imagine due to the many zeroes in $AB$: We must have

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} P $$

where $P$ is *some* invertible $2\times 2$ matrix. Then, however, we can compute how $B$ must look to get the right product, namely

$$ B = P^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Putting those together we get

$$ BA = P^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} P $$

which you can multiply out and see that the $P$s cancel out.

Comment: I got that it forms a diagonalization equation. The diagonal matrix is the matrix with its diagonal entries $2$. What can we infer from this?

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy: The product of the two explicitly given factors in the last equation is $2I$. It commutes with everything!

Comment: You are very right! Thank you very much Mr Henning!